# Can coexist in the same Python project pipenv and setuptools?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, setuptools, pipenv

I'm confused about these two libraries. In the same project does it make sense having both `pipenv` and `setuptools`? I'm writing a cli in `click` and using `setuptools` simplify the life. Also managing dependencies with `pipenv` simply the life.

Comment: so what is the problem? why doesn't it make sense to you to have both?

Comment: Because I need to mantain in two different places a list of dependencies that my project use and of course they are not in sync together automatically

Answer (score 1):

`pipenv` can import dependencies from `setuptools` style `setup.py` files. It does so when called as: `pipenv install -e .`

In a `Pipfile` this looks like:

```
[packages]
"YourPackageName" = {path = ".", editable = true}
```